# Deploying Angular App on AWS for practice

Tags: angular

I have an AngularJS app which we need to deploy on production.

As of now for development, we deployed it on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance and using grunt serve to run it.

I know grunt should be used only for development, so what are the other ways to deploy Angular App on AWS? I see many answers for deploying it on S3/Cloudfront. Can't we use EC2 instance with Nginx/Tomcat for this purpose on production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Benefit of using S3 and Cloudfront for AngularJs App :

1. S3 server static content and AngularJs is SPA model serve only javascript, HTML and css
2. Using Cloudfront and S3 content can be serve more faster compare to EC2.
3. In cost wise benefit is more compare to EC2
4. No need to run grunt while rendering content
5. If you used EC2 for SSL certificate required Load Balancer for configuration of HTTPS.
6. In CloudFront easy to configure HTTPS using S3.

I suggest go ahead with combination of Route53 + CloudFront + S3 website hosting for AngularJs app. If you need HTTPS you can get certificate from AWS ACM in very low price also.